# Looking for software tools to help localize text in images

Tags: image, localization, internationalization, translation

When websites and other applications are localized to different languages, I can imagine that a common problem is that if you have images that contain some kind of text in them, you'd want to be able to easily replace that text, rather than manually edit the image multiple times for each of the languages you support.

In our company, we have a Photoshop plugin that allows you to replace tokens in a Photoshop file with a translation that's stored in a database. This solution is adequate in that it allows text in, say, 20 files to be automatically replaced without having to manually tweak the design 20 times. It's also nice because any effects applied to the text (rotation, gradients, etc,) remain unchanged in the translations.

But this solution is also limited in that the tool must be manually run every time a translation changes, and the actual translated images are just static files that must be copied into locale-specific directories on the website.

I can imagine that this is a problem that has been solved before, and I can imagine a billion different things to make it more robust. A few ideas:

1) Run-time text replacement in images, rather than having static files stored on the file system. (This would eliminate the need to tweak images whenever the text changes.)

2) The ability to define how certain situations are handled, like, a translation that takes up twice as much space as another language.

3) The ability to specify replacement fonts for certain scripts; for example, if the source image uses a bold sans-serif font, the Japanese translation could use a similarly-styled font.

Do such tools exist, and what are they called?

Comment: Are these images for a Website? Why not let the text float on top of a background image?

Comment: Yes, this is for a website. The problem with having the text float over an image is that we want the flexibility to have interesting effects applied to the image. For example, rotation, gradients, etc. This text is created/styled by artists, not by programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a product out there called **Scene7** that does dynamic image building on the fly:

http://www.adobe.com/solutions/web-experience-management/scene7-new.html?s_tnt=68468:1:0

> **Dynamic banners** Create targeted and localized marketing images and
>   banners using templates, allowing you to deliver a segmented
>   experience on demand that increases conversion and engages customers
>   on a personal level. ([source](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/web-experience-management/dynamic-media.html))